# Where do I add php code to submit an HTML form?

Tags: php, component, custom-component, form, restful-api

I am new to Joomla, and so far, I used the basics to make a simple website. I decided to try out making a component, using JCB, that has a database of a list of items, and for each item, there is a list of checkboxes. What I want to do is submit the name of the item and the list of checked boxes to a bash script and run the bash script when I click on the submit button. But I do not know in which .php file I have to add the php function that will get called by the form action.

This is what my site view looks like for the checkboxes:

```
<form method="post">
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
<?php foreach ($this->items as $item): ?>
  <label class="btn btn-primary">
    <input type="checkbox" name="test[]" onClick="this.checked=!this.checked;"> <?php echo $item->testcase; ?>
  </label>
<?php endforeach; ?>
<input type="submit" name ="Submit">
</div>
</form>
```

Can anyone help me with this issue? I would essentially like to know where I can add a php function to act as the form action. Thanks, and let me know if I should provide any other details.

Comment: Welcome to JSE and thank you for posting a good first question.  Please take our [tour] while you wait for support/feedback.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Sourcerer` Extension for Joomla available here: https://regularlabs.com/sourcerer.

This extension allows you to embed any HTML/CSS/JS/PHP on a simple article. To do so:

1. Upload your script(s) on a folder inside your Joomla structure
2. Create a new article with this content and publish it:

> {source}<?php include JPATH_SITE.'/path/to/myfile.php'; {/source}

3. Add a menu entrie of this article if you want :)

Comment: While this may be a viable solution, it is a little light on detail/implementation.  Please be prepared to offer more specific guidance if the OP requests it.

Comment: thank you so much for your help A973C and especially mickmackusa. however i decided i would just work with what i know best, which is python, hence i am instead making a flask microserver to deal with the form. i know this is wasted potential of joomla, but i realized i cannot make use of these stuff without knowing php. sorry, and thanks again.